# Sealing what appears to be a non standard overflow drain

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, bathtub, drainage, sealing

I have an overflow drain, as seen in the picture provided, that isn't sealed. The common wisdom I've read online has been to seal with a gasket, but my drain doesn't seem to be anything like the ones I've seen.

I've also purchased a standard overflow gasket and it's a no go.

Does anyone have any idea how I can seal this drain?

[image: overflow drain]

This is the hardware that it's connected to and the gasket I bought thinking it might work.

[image: hardware and gasket 1]
[image: hardware and gasket 2]

Comment: Do you have the hardware that attaches?  What does the backside of that look like?

Comment: If you can't find a proper seal, you could always try sealing it up with some silicone caulking. Sure, not the "proper" way, but nobody will see it, and the bathtub isn't usually filled that full anyway.

Comment: Was there a leak that prompted you to take the escutcheon cover off? if no leak then Are you assuming its not sealed because you do  not see anything resembling a seal on your side of the tub. In the photo below of toyrunrs over flow you can see the gasket, that gasket gets sandwiched or pulled to the BACK of the tub when you attach the corresponding parts from the front side. Do you know your gasket is missing? what does the purchased "standard" gasket look like and why is it a no go?

Comment: thanks for the photo. the gasket you show goes on the back side of the tub. Have you tried twisting the white part on yours to see if you can unscrew it from the overflow pipe?  i  suspect that the white part with the screw holes is threaded into the overflow pipe sandwiching the gasket to the back of the tub. Again how do you know it is not sealed?

Comment: @Alaskaman I know that it's not sealed because that part specifically is dripping/pouring into the basement below the bathroom. Showering in the tub does not leak downstairs. Also there is a clear gap and open air with no gasket in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: plumber's putty][image: also Plumber's Putty]

When you have an odd-ball thing in the plumbing that needs sealed and you really can't find a thing made to seal it (and it's DWV, not pressurized supply) reach for a tub of plumber's putty...

There should be a gasket as seen in @toyrunrs recent question...

[image: tub overflow gasket]

Comment: Plumber puddy makes sense. I'm confused about the gasket part though. The pipe has no give so I can't fit a gasket between the tub and the pipe.  The cover doesn't appear to be sealable either.